# Scaling / Transforming an Object from an Image

Tags: modeling, image

I am not exactly sure how to describe this, as I am new to blender. I want to make a 3d model of a gun for a project I am working on. How exactly would I scale / transform an object like at 3:46 of this video: *https://youtu.be/qM7LhN7N7o8?t=226*

Comment: Which object do you mean? The gun he's starting to create or the reference image?

Comment: The gun, you can see him sort of line up certain lines to fit the reference image.

Comment: Apart from that part being a very quick timelapse where you can't see much, it looks like you should first start with beginner tutorials where you can learn the absolute basics, i.e. how to move vertices, create faces, extrude, rotate, scale... because that's all there is to see in the timelapse, he's moving a few vertices until they are lining up and that's all.